# Convert the 1 to zero and the zero to 1 based on a specific way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df which has only 0 and 1 values with a thousand rows and columns. I want to move through the columns with
a sliding window of 4 and in each window I want to convert the values of 1
to zero, and also change the value before/and after the 1 (it can be one number or be multiple 1 beside each other) to 1.

For example, In row with id=1, I want to change:

```
window 1 : 0 ,1 ,1 ,1 -----> 1, 0,0,0
window 2 : 0 ,0 ,1 ,1 -----> 0, 1,0,0
window 3 : 1 ,0 ,0 ,0 -----> 0, 1,0,0
```

If we have 1 at the end of the window, or at the first column of the window, only I change the 1 to 0.

Here is my df:

```
data = {
    'Ids': {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 1},
    'val1': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0},
    'val2': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1},
    'val3': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
    'val4': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
    'val5': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
    'val6': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1},
    'val7': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1},
    'val8': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
    'val9': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0},
    'val10': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0},
    'val11': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1},
    'val12': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1},
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

the desired output:

```
val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6 val7 val8  val9    val10   val11   val12
1        0      0       0        0      1     0     0   0   0   1   0
0        1      0       0        0      1     1     0   0   1   0   1
1        0      0       0        1      0     0     0   0   1   0   0
```

I already ask a question related to this question, and finally I reached to this solution:

```
def pre_snpback(df, window_size):


    output_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for i in range(0, df.shape[1]-window_size, window_size ):
        
        window = df.iloc[:, i + 1:i + 1 + window_size]
        
        print(window)
        
        x = window.shift(1, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
        
        y = window.shift(-1, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)

        df_w = (x | y) * ~window.astype(bool)
        
        df_w.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

        output_df = pd.concat([output_df,df_w], axis=1)
        
    return output_df

new_df = pre_snpback(df, 4)
```

However, when I apply it to my df with a large number of rows and columns, The results are not true. Could you please
help me with that? Am I missing anything in the code?

I can not share my data here. However, one example that does not work for me is (with window size of 32):

```
data = {f'{i}': 1 if 406 <= i <= 413 else 0 for i in range(384, 417)}

df = pd.DataFrame([data])

pre_snpback(df, 32)
```

Comment: When I run your code I get your desired dataframe. Can you make an example where the output is wrong?

Comment: Hi Andrej, thank you. You already help me with the previous one also. I just update the question. I hope the updated version can help.

Comment: I don't want to see your whole data. Just a small example where the the `pre_snpback(df, 4)` has wrong output. The sample data could have 4 or 8 columns, few rows, that's enough.

Comment: My problem is exactly that. When I run on a simple example with different scenarios, or even with a a small part of my data, it works. But, when I want to use it on my large df, it has some error. I dont know why! For example, with a window size of 28, a row with 25 first values as zero, and 3 last rows as 1 is one of the wrong answer for this code. When I create a new df with the same row, code works. But in the main df, the result of this row is not true.

Comment: maybe it's index issue. Try to call it with `pre_snpback(df.reset_index(drop=True), 4)`

Comment: @AndrejKesely I just update the question with one example that it can not shift the columns to right! Can you please take a look at it? Thank you.

Comment: I've posted and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but as I understand it, the code below may help you find the answer to your question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def transform_window(window):
    if window[0] == 1 or window[-1] == 1:
        return np.zeros_like(window)
    else:
        return np.logical_not(window).astype(int)

data = {
    'Ids': {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 1},
    'val1': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0},
    'val2': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1},
    'val3': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
    'val4': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
    'val5': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
    'val6': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1},
    'val7': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1},
    'val8': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
    'val9': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0},
    'val10': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0},
    'val11': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1},
    'val12': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1},
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

window_size = 4
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for col in range(1, len(row) - window_size + 2):
        window = row[col:col+window_size].values
        transformed_window = transform_window(window)
        df.loc[idx, df.columns[col:col+window_size]] = transformed_window

print(df)
```

Don't hesitate to ask if you have any problems with the code or anything else.

Comment: Thank you. But it does not work. The result is not same as the desired output.

Comment: Could you provide more details about your issue? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I think your code change the all zeros after 1, you can compare the last three column of the desired output with the output of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample you've posted, probably it's off-by-one error?

Initial `df`:

```py
data = {
    f'{i}': 1 if 406 <= i <= 413 else 0 for i in range(384, 417)
}
df = pd.DataFrame([data])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   384  385  386  387  388  389  390  391  392  393  394  395  396  397  398  399  400  401  402  403  404  405  406  407  408  409  410  411  412  413  414  415  416
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0
```

Then:

```py
def pre_snpback(df, window_size):
    output_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for i in range(0, df.shape[1]-window_size, window_size ):
        window = df.iloc[:, i:i + 1 + window_size]              # <-- removed `+ 1` here
        x = window.shift(1, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
        y = window.shift(-1, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
        df_w = (x | y) * ~window.astype(bool)
        df_w.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        output_df = pd.concat([output_df,df_w], axis=1)

    return output_df

print(pre_snpback(df, 32))
```

Prints:

```
   384  385  386  387  388  389  390  391  392  393  394  395  396  397  398  399  400  401  402  403  404  405  406  407  408  409  410  411  412  413  414  415  416
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes. This is correct here, but for me it does not work!! So strange. This made me crazy these days. The column 414 is still 0 for me. I only copy and paste your code with exactly same dataframe and etc. :(